# Qual a diferença entre Function e Procedure?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, procedure, funções

Qual são as diferenças entre as duas, e exemplos de onde e geralmente são usadas.

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/pl-sql-functions-e-procedures/29882 Olhe se pode te ajudar.

Comment: De qual banco de dados estamos falando?

Answer (score 13):

Funções e procedures servem propósitos diferentes.

Uma função, pensando na sua definição matemática, é usada normalmente para calcular um valor com base num determinado input. Uma função não permite alterações fora do seu "scope" (escopo), isto é, não pode ser utilizada para alterar o estado global da base de dados (por exemplo, através das instruções INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

As funções podem ser incorporada directamente numa instrução de SQL caso retornem um valor escalar

```
SELECT udf_DiaSemana(data_hoje)
```

Ou podem ser usadas numa junção caso retornem uma tabela

```
SELECT t1.Var1, f1.Var2
FROM tbl_tabela1 t1
INNER JOIN udf_Exemplo(parametro) f1
   ON f1.Var1 = t1.Var1
```

Por seu lado, as procedures podem ser vistas como programas/scripts (se fizermos uma analogia com uma qualquer linguagem de programação). Uma procedure permite alterar o estado global da base de dados (por exemplo, a utilização das instruções INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). Procedures são utilizadas normalmente para juntar várias queries numa única transacção.

Pequenas diferenças entre os dois conceitos:

- Podemos executar uma função a partir de uma procedure, mas não podemos fazer o inverso.
- Podemos usar funções em conjunto com as instruções SELECT, WHERE, HAVING mas não é possível fazer o mesmo com procedures.
- Procedures permitem efectuar o tratamento de excepções, via try/catch. Já o mesmo não é possível numa função.

Answer (score 8):

resumidamente: funções retornam valores, procedures não.